# Как исправить баг командной строки?

Tags: python, pip

Всем добрый день. Возникла проблема с командной строкой. питон устанавливал в microsoft store для windows 10 Пытаюсь установить библиотеку, выскакивает ошибка, причем ошибка вообще непонятная. Устанавливаю библиотеку в PyCharm, пишет обновите pip, обновляю pip - ошибка. Замкнутый круг. Может это баг версии командной строки? Как это исправить? Заранее большое спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pygame
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\iljal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install pygame': ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.
```

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install --upgrade pip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\iljal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip3.exe" install --upgrade pip': ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.
```

```
  WARNING: The script automat-visualize.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я написал quit(), чтобы показать версию питона. Запускаю ком. строку, всё равно при попытке что либо утсановить или обновить - ошибка, либо с ? знаками либо ошибка с каким-то "wheel"

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pygame
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\iljal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install pygame': ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.

Comment: Попробуйте `python -m pip install ...`.

Comment: В основном тексте норм добавил. И так возникает не только с PyGame, так возникает с любой библиотекой, которую хочу установить

Comment: да, библиотеку теперь могу устанавливать, спасибо Вам большое. Скажите пожалуйста, а как обновить pip, так как тоже возникает ошибка при обновлении?

Comment: Извините, вот ком. строка мне сообщение вывело, оно python что ли не видит?   WARNING: The script automat-visualize.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Comment: Откуда Вы `Python` устанавливали?

Comment: питон устанавливал в microsoft store для windows 10

Comment: питон устанавливал в microsoft store для windows 10

Comment: сейчас удалю и установлю питон с python.org

Comment: Хорошее решение.

Comment: переустановил, но ошибка абсолютно та же... Скачал питон 3.8.3, пытаюсь установить иблиотеку, опять та же ошибка: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install scarpy
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\iljal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install scarpy': ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.`

Comment: Как мне удалить все накопившиеся python'ы на своем пк? Я кучу раз уже переустанавливал, но какие-то старые остались. Как их полностью удалить?